# Understanding an R function and finding its equivalent in Python 3

Tags: python, r, python-3.x, geolocation, geospatial

I have an R function that I can't fully understand, and I would also like to know what would be its exact equivalent in Python. This is the code:

```
distGeo(as.matrix(all_df[,c('longitude','latitude')]), c(0,0))
```

I know the library used here is `geosphere`, and I also know this code is used to get the geodesic distance between 2 points. But I can't figure the way its working here. in the `geosphere` [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/geosphere/versions/1.5-10/topics/distGeo) for this function `distGeo`, they say `p1` can be a vector of lat lon coordinates, or a matrix of 2 columns.

I see the lat lon here is being taken as a matrix with this 2 columns with latitude and longitude, but later we have the `p2` part, they say it must be the second reference point to calculate the geodesic distance from. And if `p2` is missing, then the distance is calculated between the points given in `p1`.

Now the question is: what would be the value of `p2` in this case? Is it the vector `c(0,0)`? or is the distance being computed between the latitude and longitude passed in `p1`? if so, how is this even possible since the distance would be calculated between a single vector of latitude coordinates and a single vector of longitude coordinates? to get something meaningful one would need to calculate the distances between 2 pairs of complete lat lon coordinates vectors right?

And the most important, what is the role of the vector `c(0,0)` here? and what would be the exact equivalent of this line of code in Python 3?

I have seen 2 packages that can handle this, one is the [`Geopy`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package, and the second one is the [`pyproj`](http://pyproj4.github.io/pyproj/stable/) package. But here we must specify the type of ellipsoid we are using to project our coordinates into, and in the R piece of code there is no ellipsoid type given, it seems like is not a mandatory argument to pass to the `distGeo` function to compute the distances.

Any help with this will be much appreciated. Thank you very much in advance

Comment: The `c(0,0)` seems to be the `p2` argument. The distances are being computed between the points in each row of the `p1` matrix and `0, 0` (standard recycling of length 1 vectors in R). The documentation also states that the default ellipsoid is WGS84, presumably your Python packages don't set a default and require you to supply one.

Comment: So the distances are being calculated from this lat lon vectors and a vector `c(0,0)`? What would be the sense of this? why `c(0,0)`? And yes in the python packages we can specify the ellipsoid type too, the same ellipsoids exists in both python and R packages

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to calculate distances from `0, 0`, that would depend on where you got this line of code from. It looks more like example of usage to me; the documentation example is `distGeo(c(0,0),c(90,90))`

Comment: no no is not an example. You can find the original code [here](https://github.com/drivendataorg/pump-it-up/blob/master/madRid/PumpItUp_DataDriven_2nd_place_madRid_team.R), maybe by looking at its context you will understand what i didn't

Comment: Ok, looks like they are feature engineering for a random forest. So basically they just want to do different transformations on the input data to maybe get some more structure. Not familiar with this data but you might expect that distance from some arbitrary point adds a bit more info than just including lat/lon as features, though perhaps a less arbitrary point would add even more

Comment: Allright, that adds some sense to the matter, they just chose a random point and expected the distances calculated from this point to add some more information, that sounds logic, but you are right, maybe selecting a meaningful point would derive in a more logical and better approach. Thank you very much for your help with this buddy :)